# Custom buck converter putting out 1V instead of 5V

Tags: power-supply, buck

I "designed" a simple buck converter, which is basically a clone of the 5V reference design in the TPS6293x datasheet. Unfortunately, my converter is only putting about 1V (closer to 0.95V). This voltage is independent of the input voltage, and I've reproduced it on two separate boards. I used a multimeter to verify the two resistors in the voltage divider are accurate.

I'm unsure what else to check. The voltage being regulated, just at the wrong level, makes me think something is wrong with the resistor divider, but the values match the example reference design almost exactly.

Here is my schematic and board layout:

[image: schematic]

[image: layout]

Comment: Have you checked the waveform at the inductor, and at the output, with an oscilloscope?

Comment: With the scope connected to pin 1 of the inductor and ground, I see the inductor ringing (a decaying sinewave). Connected between pin 2 and ground, I see a flat line, with some 60Hz ripple on top of it.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong.  Is the FB pin sitting at 0.8 V as you change the line and load?  As @BeB00 said looking at the switch node on a 'scope might provide a clue also.  Do you just have 1 board acting this way?  Can you swap out the IC?

Comment: @StephenD. The inductor ringing that you see could be normal for discontinuous mode (light loads).  Does the ringing go away as you increase the output current toward full load?  The ringing should start after the switch node goes low for some period and the inductor "runs out" of current.  This happens when the part is operating in "diode emulation mode".

Comment: @JohnD I have 2 boards acting this way. I can solder up another if needed for confirmation, but that's the last board I have. FB is sitting at 0.13V. I don't have an easy way to try increasing the load current as I don't have any kind of adjustable load and the converter is rated for a few amps, so I'd imagine I need at least an amp to get it out of diode emulation mode. If that's the next troubleshooting step I can try to rig something up.

Comment: @StephenD. what do you see on Vin? could you post all of your oscilloscope traces (inductor and Vin)?

Comment: If you have the time and the will, removing the grid and add more contrast to the schematic would be superb.

Comment: please turn off the grid when taking a screenshot of the schematic diagram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C15 isn't connected properly. It should go between the BST (pin-6) and SW (pin-5) pins. This is the bootstrap capacitor which provides the level-sifted voltage necessary to drive the high-side transistor.

Comment: Great catch, thank you. I'm going to fix that either tonight or tomorrow and will accept this answer if it works.

Comment: Worked great, and I didn't even need a bodge wire due to the layout of the board! Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, good catch, can't believe I didn't notice that either :)